# OpenGL Java Get Properties of 3D OBJ Model

Tags: java, 3d

I am currently working on a 3D Game but I am stuck on trying to get the height and width of the objects for some aspects of my game. So the question is, how can I get the properties of a 3D model (.obj) like height and width? Also, I am using LWJGL.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wavefront (.obj) file format doesn't specify any width/height information.

Depending on your axes convention, an easy algorithm to compute the width/height would be to go through each points mentioned in the .obj file, find the minimum and maximum for a given dimension (x, y or z) and get the distance using:

`d = |max - min|`.

Comment: +Mr_Pouet Good idea! I never thought about that. I will try to implement that!